# Can we change wake word in embedded DSP in mobile phones?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-voice, watson-conversation

I would like to create a voice interfaced app on android + ios. It would help save battery and provide easy access if I could refigure wake word (e.g. siri, ok google etc.) on my customers mobile phones. I understand amazon echo operates via DSP ( so it is not listening at all times). Wondering if mobile voice interface is also utilizing the same tech and if it possible to gain permission to access and change wake word for my app? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible, only for phone vendor. They company that sells this thing is called Sensory

Comment: Thank you Nikolay for your answer.